# How to work with c:foreach and other fields after it?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

My problem is that in my home page, I get the variable `capacidade` perfectly.
Then I have that `c:forEach` there and the other field named `"nome"`.
When I try to persist, then I get the `capacidade` field filled, but the `"nome"` attribute comes `null`.
I saw that if I push him before the `c:forEach`, then it works. But I need to keep him after `c:forEach` fields.

```xml
<s:decorate template="layout/form.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="label">capacidade:</ui:define>
            <h:inputText size="50" value="#{home.instance.capacidade}" maxlength="100" required="true" />
        </s:decorate>

        <a4j:outputPanel id="camposPresenca">
            <c:forEach items="#{home.presencas}" var="presenca" varStatus="loop">
                <s:decorate template="layout/form.xhtml">
                    <ui:define name="label">Presença #{loop.index + 1}</ui:define>
                    <rich:calendar enableManualInput="true" value="#{presenca.dataPresenca}" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" oninputblur="validarData(this);" required="true"/>
                    <h:inputText size="100" value="#{presenca.horarioPresenca}" maxlength="250" />
                </s:decorate>
            </c:forEach>
        </a4j:outputPanel>

        <s:decorate template="layout/form.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="label">Nome:</ui:define>
            <h:inputText size="50" value="#{home.instance.nome}" maxlength="100" required="true" />
```

someone knows how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<ui:repeat>` instead of `<c:forEach>` the later is not a component and are not part of the tree component after the page is built.

Read more [in this article](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat).

In General: JSTL elements break `ViewScope` beans.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `home.getInstance()` is not thread safe.

You probably have bigger problems that need to be addressed here, but one band-aid solution would be to save the instance value before doing the layout here.

Put this before your code snippet

```
<c:set var="home_instance" value = "${home.instance}"/>
```

And replace `home.instance` with `home_instance`.